# What tense should we use in the relative clause?

Tags: tense

> Last year I flew to London  to visit my cousin, who ____ ( live ) there.

The usual answer is "lives", because people consider that the situation is still relevant. But I think "lived" is also possible if he doesn't live there any more or simply referring to that time "last year". Am I right?

Comment: Yes, you are quite right.

Comment: Maybe it's not *exactly* the same context, but *Last year our hotel attracted many guests who **were** Chinese* would always use the highlighted past tense (and certainly doesn't imply that some of those guests might have been so impressed they've since decided to change their nationality! :)